# Fetching from file giving unwanted result

Tags: java, encoding, io

I am trying to write to a file by:

```
for(String s : str){
     buffer.put(s.getBytes());
     buffer.flip();
     channel.write(buffer);
      buffer.clear();
}
```

So whenever I'm fetching from file by `char c = (char)randomAccessFile.readChar();`

Here I am not getting the chars which were in the string. Can somebody tell me the reason.

One more thing why converting a `String` suppose trying to byte i.e. `string.getBytes()` it is giving 6 bytes. But we know that char takes `2` bytes so it should be `16*6=96`.

Comment: Where does 16*6 come from?  Are you trying to say your string has 48 characters?

Comment: @Pace 1 char= 16bits and we have 6 char.

Comment: Ok.  Then you would expect 12 bytes, which would be 96 bits.  You are right that a char takes 2 bytes of memory.  However, String.getBytes() is not returning the same representation that Java is using in memory.  The size of the byte array returned will depend on the encoding that is being used to generate the bytes.  Here is an [example](http://rextester.com/UCEB42773) of that phenomenon.

Comment: @Pace That means in my system the default encoding is UTF-8. In UTF-8 char (a,b,c.....) is 8 bit than integer suppose 1 is also 8 bit because its also a char i.e. '1'. Am i correct?

Comment: The default encoding is determined by the OS (and likely locale dependent).  With a typical US Windows 7 system I get a default of windows-1252.  You can inspect the default with Charset.defaultCharset() and set the default with a JVM property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RandomAccessFile` expects the bytes to be the memory representation of the underlying string.  When you call `String.getBytes()` you are getting a standard representation of the underlying string.  Here is example code which works with a `RandomAccessFile`.  Notice that it is not using `getBytes()` but casting the underlying `char` to a `byte` instead.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "foo";

    SeekableByteChannel channel = Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get("C:\\tmp\\foo.txt"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        buffer.put((byte)(ch >> 8));
        buffer.put((byte)ch);
    }
    buffer.flip();
    channel.write(buffer);

    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("/tmp/foo.txt", "rw");
    try {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(file.readChar());
        }
    } finally {
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: Java internally stores characters in memory as UTF-16 (big endian) so you could use getBytes("UTF-16BE") if you so desired.  It's possible this is JVM dependent but I'm not sure.